# How does this code generate 100 random number

Tags: c, random

> will this work just as well for(a=0;a<100;a++)?? Why would someone
>   write code like the code below? I think I know how this code is read.
>   Does it take for loop a * b? What other ways could you write this
>   code? I have not seen any code similar on this site so I thought I
>   would create a question for it. Please help me if you can, also I am
>   new to this site.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int r,a,b;

    printf("100 Random Numbers: ");

    for (a=0; a<20; a++) {
        for (b=0; b<5; b++) {
            r=rand();
            printf("%d\t", r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `will this work just as well for(a=0;a<100;a++)??` definitely yes!, you can write it this way, inner loop is just useless in random and printing

Answer (score 1):

> Why would someone write code like the code below?

For example, to clarify that he does not generate 100 random numbers, but 20 times 5 random numbers.

In example:

```
/* Allocate strings */
ptr = malloc(392);
ptr = malloc(8 * 48 + 8 * 1);
```

Both are the same, yet, a reader will see in the second case that he allocates memory for 8 strings with 48 bytes and 8 string terminations.

Of course, he could have written `a < 20 * 5` and achieved the same.

The second possibility is that the code is just wrong. But `for` statements don't appear out of thin air. So the error is likely not that he couldn't imagine to only use one `for` loop, but likely that he intended to write something like:

```
   for (a=0; a<20; a++) {
        for (b=0; b<5; b++) {
            r=rand();
            printf("%d\t", r);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```